# Unable to Generate Dynamic Checkboxs Base on an Array

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know wha I am not able to create checkbox from the array of items

```
 var items: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'];
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   $('#checks').appendTo('<input type="checkbox">');
}
```

.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checks"> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple problems. You should use `append` instead of `appendTo` and you've got an errant `:` that should be an `=`.

```js
var obj = { items : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6'] };
for (i = 0; i < obj.items.length; i++) {
  var id = "check" + i;
  $('#checks').append('<input id="' + id + '" type="checkbox"><label for="' + id + '">' + obj.items[i] + '</label>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="checks"> </div>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave but how can we bind the items to checkbox names?

Comment: sorry, I mean how about checkbox labels?

Comment: Thanks Dave, just one more question, in case of having array in js object?!  which is for sure like `item: [], ` how to handle that?

Comment: I wrapped the array in an object. Is this what you mean?